# How to bind animationview play with LottieForms in a MVVM architecture?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, lottie

So i work with a animation in a listview and i want to play it once whenever i want, so i want to control it.

This is the library https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin

I have a class:

```
public class Info {
   public bool ReadMoreIconVisibility {get;set;}
}
```

And xaml:

```
<forms:AnimationView Animation = "animationone.json" Loop = "false" IsVisible="{Binding ReadMoreIconVisibiliy}"/>
```

I can successfully work with my xaml to hide/not hide my animation. But how do i reach the `AnimationView.Play()` method, that is only available if i name my label `x:name`.

How can i take advantage of the mvvm archictect in order to `Play`my animation?

I cannot work with the commandparameter because it is already used by another item in the same listview:

```
 <Button Command="{Binding Click}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference otherItemInListView}"/>
```

One solution could be to extend the commandparameter with another object, if so how is that achievable? Preferably there is another solution to this though.

Comment: Add a public event handler (or Action, that is what I would use) and have the "View" (ie the Page in your case) lifecycles add/remove that Action from the  ViewModel and in your setter for `ReadMoreIconVisibility` property have it execute that Action if it is assigned. The Action on the Page would of course start the Lottie Animation when executed.

Comment: `private bool _ReadMoreIconVisibiliy;
        public bool ReadMoreIconVisibiliy
        {
            get { return _ReadMoreIconVisibiliy; }
            set
            {
                // Execute action here?
                this._ReadMoreIconVisibiliy = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ReadMoreIconVisibiliy");
            }
        }`

Comment: Ah does not look to good when i post code in comments :/ But execute the action in the setter, how do i know what exact animationview it is from my bool? Since i have a few of them in my listview

Comment: Not a fix but a workaround - use messaging centre to subscribe to a message in your view that when received calles AnimationView.Play(), send a message from your viewmodel when button is clicked.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question but I am posting this answer in case anyone is facing the same problem.

What you have to do in order to use Lottie with Xamarin Forms without breaking the MVVM pattern, using a Binding from the ViewModel to start and stop the animation, is creating two trigger actions, one that plays the animation and one that resets the progress to 0 then pauses the animation. Or you can create one trigger that check

Then in your ViewModel create a bool property that is set to true when you want to start the navigation and false when you want to stop. In your case it's **ReadMoreIconVisibiliy**.

Then in your **xaml** consume the trigger, see code below.

```
<lottieForms:AnimationView
Animation="load_complete.json"
Speed="1"
AutoPlay="False">
    <lottieForms:AnimationView.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="lottieForms:AnimationView">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ReadMoreIconVisibiliy}" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <actions:StartLottieAnimationTriggerAction />
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                <actions:StopLottieAnimationTriggerAction />
            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </lottieForms:AnimationView.Triggers>
</lottieForms:AnimationView>
```

**StartLottieAnimationTriggerAction** Code

```
public class StartLottieAnimationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<AnimationView>
{
    protected override void Invoke(AnimationView sender)
    {
        sender.PlayAnimation();
    }
}
```

**StopLottieAnimationTriggerAction** Code

```
public class StopLottieAnimationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<AnimationView>
{
    protected override void Invoke(AnimationView sender)
    {
        sender.Progress = 0;
        sender.PauseAnimation();
    }
}
```