# How do I display a Lottie animation at least one time when IsBusy is true during data loading?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, loading, lottie

On my **Xamarin.Forms project**, I would like to display a **Lottie animation** during **API calls** or during the **loading of a website** in a `WebView`.

For this, I've bounded the `IsVisible` property of the **Lottie animation** to the `IsBusy` property of my **ViewModels**: this works well.

```
<lottie:AnimationView Animation="resource://lottie_loading.json?assembly=MyApp"
        AnimationSource="EmbeddedResource"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        AutoPlay="True"
        RepeatMode="Infinite"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
```

But the loading duration is sometimes very short, so I would like to found a way to **display the Lottie animation once in full before to hidden it**.

Is it possible? What would be the better approach to achieve this?

Comment: [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netcore-3.1) could help? like ```await Task.Delay(500).ConfigureAwait(false);``` in your data load method

Comment: Maybe but this will not be perfect, and I can’t do this for the WebView.

Comment: Add the delay into "OnNavigated" before update the value of IsBusy. Plus, that is not perfect as the loading time varies, and you have to find a balance between a full-length animation and real loading time.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).  You can also mark your own solution:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another approach that works, even if this solution is a bit heavy and can be improved.

Firstly, as recommended [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636061/how-to-bind-animationview-play-with-lottieforms-in-a-mvvm-architecture-xamarin), I've created 2 `Triggers`:

```
public class PlayLottieAnimationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<AnimationView>
{
    protected override void Invoke(AnimationView sender)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"PlayLottieAnimationTriggerAction()");
        sender.PlayAnimation();
    }
}

public class StopLottieAnimationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<AnimationView>
{
    protected override void Invoke(AnimationView sender)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"StopLottieAnimationTriggerAction()");
        sender.StopAnimation();
    }
}
```

I also used `EventToCommandBehaviors`, like described [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/behaviors-eventtocommandbehavior/).

After this I can use the **Lottie animation** like this:

```
<forms:AnimationView 
    x:Name="animationView" 
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    AutoPlay="True"
    IsVisible="{Binding ShowAnimation}"
    Animation="resource://lottie_4squares_apricot_blond.json?assembly=Example.Forms"
    AnimationSource="EmbeddedResource"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <forms:AnimationView.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="forms:AnimationView">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ShowAnimation}" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <triggers:LottieTriggerAction />
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                <actions:StopLottieAnimationTriggerAction />
            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </forms:AnimationView.Triggers>
    <forms:AnimationView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="OnFinishedAnimation"
            Command="{Binding OnFinishedAnimationCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{x:Reference animationView}"/>
    </forms:AnimationView.Behaviors>
</forms:AnimationView>
```

And in my **ViewModel**, I've declared a property `ShowAnimation` that is related to `IsBusy` and the Command `OnFinishedAnimationCommand` like this:

```
private bool _showAnimation;
public bool ShowAnimation
{
    get => _showAnimation;
    set => Set(ref _showAnimation, value);
}

public ICommand OnFinishedAnimationCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Xamarin.Forms.Command<object>(async (object sender) =>
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                await OnFinishedAnimation(sender);
            }
        });
    }
}

private Task OnFinishedAnimation(object sender)
{
    var view = sender as AnimationView;
    if (IsBusy)
    {
        view.PlayAnimation();
    }
    else
    {
        ShowAnimation = false;
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In case of the **Loader** is related to a `WebView`, the `ShowLoadingView` property is set like this:

```
private Task WebViewNavigatingAsync(WebNavigatingEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    IsBusy = true;
    ShowLoadingView = true;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async Task WebViewNavigatedAsync(WebNavigatedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

But, as I also display an **ErrorView** in case of issues (timeout, unreachable server, ...) and a Reload/Retry button, I had to add some code:

```
private async Task WebViewNavigatedAsync(WebNavigatedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    IsBusy = false;
    // for display loading animation on Refresh
    while (ShowLoadingView)
        await Task.Delay(50);
    SetServiceError();
}
```

In case of the **Loader** is related to **Data loading**, the `ShowLoadingView` property is set like this:

```
private async Task GetNewsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    try
    {
        ShowErrorView = false;
        ErrorKind = ServiceErrorKind.None;
        IsBusy = true;
        ShowLoadingView = true;
        var _news = await _dataService.GetNews(forceRefresh);
        News = new ObservableCollection<News>(_news);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorKind = ServiceErrorKind.ServiceIssue;
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
        await SetServiceError();
    }
```

}

However, I noticed that in some cases the `SetServiceError()` was not fired, as `OnFinishedAnimation()` was called in the same time. I haven't yet investigated, but I've fixed this by adding the call to `SetServiceError()` in in `OnFinishedAnimation()`:

```
private async Task OnFinishedAnimation(object sender)
{
    var view = sender as AnimationView;
    if (IsBusy)
    {
        view.PlayAnimation();
    }
    else
    {
        ShowLoadingView = false;
        // fix SetServiceError() call issue
        await SetServiceError();
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to tell what could be done to optimize this.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to display a Lottie animation during **API calls**

```
public async void loadData()
{
    //Data load started
    viewModel.IsBusy = true;

    await methodOfLoadingData...;

    //Data load finished
     viewModel.IsBusy = false;
}
```

> during the loading of a website in a WebView：

```
private void MyWebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.IsBusy = true;
}

private void MyWebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.IsBusy = false;
}
```

> But the loading duration is sometimes very short

The loading duration is depending on the time you completely loading the data/webview. If you load the data/webview very fast, the loading duration should be short.