# Lottie IsPlaying and Loop replacement xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, lottie

I just updated to the latest version of Lottie; we are using Xamarin forms and now my app is crashing because it cannot find

1. IsPlaying
2. Loop

Can anyone tell me by what have they been replaced by?

Cannot find anything suggesting the replacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been playing around with lottie in XF a bit lately and I think I can help you.

> 1. IsPlaying

I think this has been replaced with `IsAnimating="{Binding IsAnimating}"`.

> 2. Loop

There is no exact replacement for this. If you want an infinite loop you can use `RepeatMode="Infinite"` and omit to set the `RepeatCount` field.

If you want to play the animation for a specific number of times you can skip the `RepeatMode` field and instead just set `RepeatCount="1"`. This will repeat the animation one time. If you want it to only play one time and then stop you can skip the `RepeatCount` field entirely or set it to `RepeatCount="0"`

The `RepeatMode` field can probably be combined with the `RepeatCount` field too but I haven't tested the different modes of that yet.

Here is a sample from my xaml. It loops animation.json infinite.

```
<forms:AnimationView
    x:Name="animationView"
    Animation="animation.json"
    AutoPlay="True"
    RepeatMode="Infinite"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Comment: Sorry just seen this .I am using specially to bind to IsBusy and display an animating progress bar  e.g IsPlaying={Binding IsBusy} so how do you suggest I map it? Noticed that there are methods now e.g ShowAnimation etc seems much more complicated as in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704116/xamarin-forms-how-to-display-a-lottie-animation-at-least-one-time-when-isbusy-i

Comment: @developer9969 You could try IsAnimating="{Binding IsBusy}"

Comment: RepeatMode = "Infinite", is actually the best way to substitute Loop = "true".