# How play lottie animation in MVVM using Command?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, lottie

This is my content page and i need to play the lottie animation using command in my MVVM
how do i achieve this? Please help me

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<lottie:AnimationView 
AnimationSource="AssetOrBundle" 
Animation="Animation.json" 
AutoPlay="False" 
Command="{Binding Command}"
x:Name="MyAnimation"/>
```

This is my ViewModel Example how can i play the lottie animation using command, I cant use the click because the lottie animation is inside of my CollectionView.

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableObject 
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
         Command = new Command(ExecuteCommand);
    }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    private void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        // How do i play the animation?
        // MyAnimation.PlayAnimation();
    }
}
```

Im creating animation button that will fire when you like the post in collection view for example

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/59738020/199364

Comment: "I cant use the click because the lottie animation is inside of my CollectionView" - this is not true